# angular child inside child

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have a problem with the recursion in angularJs.

I want to repeat all names from JSON file:
    Here is my JSON file structure:

```
var data = {
    "id": "580",
    "name": "test",
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "parentId": null,
    "children": [
        {
            "id": "581",
            "name": "test 2",
            "status": "ACTIVE",
            "parentId": "580",
            "children": [{
                "id": "594",
                "name": "test 3",
                "status": "ACTIVE",
                "parentId": "581",
                "children": []
            }]
        }
    ]
}
```

All I want is just to know how to make ng-repeat children in children?

Comment: How many levels of children are there? As far as I know, you can't use `ng-repeat` recursively.

Comment: Those childrens could generates dynamicly. So i dont have any idea how many should be there!

Comment: google `angular recursive tree` should find lots of solutions, modules, directives etc

Comment: is there `{children:[ { children:{ children:[{...}]}}]}`. is children array or object?

Answer (score 3):

You should use an ng-template in order to use it recursive.

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="exampleTree">
{{ x.name }}
    <ul ng-if="x.children">
        <li ng-repeat="x in x.children" ng-include="'exampleTree'">           
        </li>
    </ul>
</script>
```

To use this template and run it:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="x in data" ng-include="'exampleTree'"></li>
</ul>
```

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/tdfgjjj4/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-repeat with a template so it goes as far as you have data. Here is an example:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.child = {
    "id": "580",
    "name": "test",
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "parentId": null,
    "children": [{
      "id": "581",
      "name": "test 2",
      "status": "ACTIVE",
      "parentId": "580",
      "children": [{
        "id": "594",
        "name": "test 3",
        "status": "ACTIVE",
        "parentId": "581",
        "children": []
      }]
    }]
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">

  <!-- This is the template that can be repeated in itself-->
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="childView">
    {{child.name}}
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="child in child.children" ng-include="'childView'"></li>
    </ul>
  </script>

  <!-- This is the initial use for the template-->
  <div ng-include="'childView'"></div>

</body>
```

I had to put child 594 in an array so it would work.